# Loading associated entities in one query

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I have the following code which works but I believe it is performing multiple look ups just to get the "Account" entity that is associated with my custom "Project" entity.

Is it possible to specify which associated entities you would like populated without having to loop through the initial result set?

```
    public IList<new_project> GetAssociatedProjectsByPostcode(string postcode)
    {
        FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
        filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
        filter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("new_project_zippostalcode", ConditionOperator.Equal, postcode));

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.EntityName = new_project.EntityLogicalName;
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
        query.Criteria = filter;

        OrganizationServiceCache serviceCache = new OrganizationServiceCache(MemoryCache.Default, base.CrmConnection);

        using (CachedOrganizationService service = new CachedOrganizationService(CrmConnection, serviceCache))
        using (XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext = new XrmServiceContext(service))
        {
             //Run the query to return the project entities in a list
             IList<new_project> projects = service.RetrieveMultiple(query)
                                            .Entities
                                            .Select(item => item.ToEntity<new_project>())
                                            .ToList<new_project>();

             //Define the relationships we want populated
             Relationship accountRel = new Relationship("new_account_new_project");

             //We cannot call load property with tracking turned on 
             xrmServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

             //Loop through the original list and get our associations
             foreach (new_project np in projects)
                 xrmServiceContext.LoadProperty(np, accountRel);

             return projects;
        }            
    }
```

Is it possible to produce the equivalent with the ServiceContext?

```
Select Project.Name, Account.Name
From Project
Join Account ON Account.Id = Project.AccountId
```

**EDIT :**

After using the link entities as described by James below I now have the following which produces an entity collection with projects and accounts populated in one query but I cannot transfer this flat dataset into the hierarchical object structure.

```
        public IList<new_project> GetAssociatedProjectsByPostcode(string postcode)
    {
        FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
        filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
        filter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("new_project_zippostalcode", ConditionOperator.BeginsWith, PostcodeUtility.RegionFromPostcode(postcode)));

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.EntityName = new_project.EntityLogicalName;
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
        query.Criteria = filter;

        query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity(new_project.EntityLogicalName, Account.EntityLogicalName, "new_associatedaccountid", "accountid", JoinOperator.Inner));
        query.LinkEntities[0].Columns = new ColumnSet(true);
        query.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = Account.EntityLogicalName;

        OrganizationServiceCache serviceCache = new OrganizationServiceCache(MemoryCache.Default, base.CrmConnection);

        using (CachedOrganizationService service = new CachedOrganizationService(CrmConnection, serviceCache))
        using (XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext = new XrmServiceContext(service))
        {
            EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            //*****************************************************************
            //The entity collection is now populated with the accounts but they
            //are just additional key value pairs
            //e.g. (String)((AliasedValue)ec[0]["account.name"]).Value;
            //*****************************************************************

            //Turn the entity collection into our class structure
            IList<new_project> projects = ec.Entities
                                           .Select(item => item.ToEntity<new_project>())
                                           .ToList<new_project>();
            return projects;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this should be pretty straight forward, you have a couple of options.

1. FetchXml, this is an xml syntax, similar in approach to tsql, it doesn't have all the features but you can do joins with `link-entity` as shown here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328117.aspx).
2. `QueryExpression`, has a `LinkEntities` property which can be used like this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328149.aspx).
3. You could issue a `RetrieveRequest`, populating the `RelatedEntitiesQuery` as shown [here](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/querying-crm-relationships/).

---

**Edit**

So the entity collection looks like its returning the results I would expect (e.g. the accounts and values of those accounts) - I take it typeof(ec[0]) is Entity?

So its just the conversion to an early bound which is going wrong.

I havnt used linq to crm much, so I'm starting to guess, but from looking at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334754.aspx).

You may just need to:

1. EnableProxyTypes on your service, apparently this is required for full early bound support.
2. Cast the entity to your early bound type.

For example (from the sample):

```
_serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

Account retrievedAccount = (Account)_serviceProxy.Retrieve("account", _accountId, cols);

retrievedAccount.Address1_PostalCode = "98052";
```

Retrieve just returns an Entity (the type of EntityCollection.Entities) and casting seems to work here.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  I now have the query working using the LinkEntities option but I cannot get the projects and accounts to cast into the correct entities. ToEntity only allows me to obtain the base object, this looses all the additional account fields I have returned, do you have any ideas how I can populate the Account as an object. My loop seems to do this but it would be nicer in one query.

Comment: You might just have to use it the generic Entity class, can you post your code? Also are you using early or late bound types?

Comment: Latest code added. I have used the CrmSvcUtil.exe util to create the early bound classes. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I should also add that I tried the RetrieveRequest method but as I need multiple results (EntityCollection rather than Entity) I had to use RetrieveMultipleRequest and that did not have a RelatedEntities property that I could see.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help but this seems to be taking me back to looping through my result set and issuing a single retrieve per entity. Daryl seems to suggest that it is a limitation and I will either need to work with the entity collection instead of my object graph or use his static helper class. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I didn't mean you should perform a seperate retrieve for each record, I was just using that snippet as a demonstration of casting from `Entity` to your strongly typed class.

Comment: May have found a better example of how to cast from late to early and vice versa: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309586.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Edited From James Wood's Comment...
You can retrieve child entities child entities for an entity using the [Retrieve Request](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/querying-crm-relationships/).  You have to have the parent entity's GUID in order for it to work though... You can, on the other hand, include values from child entities by adding columns to the column collection of the linked entity.  You can specify an Aliased name or just accept the default.

I've made extensive use of these Extension methods for accessing the Aliased Values from the parent entities:

```
    // This needs to be placed in a public static class and it's namespace added as a using to whatever class you'd like to use it in

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the Aliased Value for a column specified in a Linked entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the aliased attribute form the linked entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <param name="attributeName">The aliased attribute from the linked entity.  Can be preappeneded with the
    /// linked entities logical name and a period. ie "Contact.LastName"</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T GetAliasedValue<T>(this Entity entity, string attributeName)
    {
        string aliasedEntityName = SplitAliasedAttributeEntityName(ref attributeName);

        AliasedValue aliased;
        foreach (var attribute in entity.Attributes.Values)
        {
            aliased = attribute as AliasedValue;
            if(entity.IsAttributeAliasedValue(attributeName, aliasedEntityName, aliased))
            {
                try
                {
                    return (T)aliased.Value;
                }
                catch (InvalidCastException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidCastException(
                        String.Format("Unable to cast attribute {0}.{1} from type {2} to type {3}",
                                aliased.EntityLogicalName, aliased.AttributeLogicalName,
                                typeof(T).Name, aliased.Value.GetType().Name));
                }
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Aliased value with attribute " + attributeName +
            " was not found!  Only these attributes were found: " + String.Join(", ", entity.Attributes.Keys));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the Aliased Value for a column specified in a Linked entity, returning the default value for 
    /// the type if it wasn't found
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the aliased attribute form the linked entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <param name="attributeName">The aliased attribute from the linked entity.  Can be preappeneded with the
    /// linked entities logical name and a period. ie "Contact.LastName"</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T GetAliasedValueOrDefault<T>(this Entity entity, string attributeName)
    {
        T value;
        if (entity.HasAliasedAttribute(attributeName))
        {
            value = entity.GetAliasedValue<T>(attributeName);
        }
        else
        {
            value = default(T);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static bool IsAttributeAliasedValue(this Entity entity, string attributeName, string aliasedEntityName, AliasedValue aliased)
    {
        bool value =
       (aliased != null &&
            (aliasedEntityName == null || aliasedEntityName == aliased.EntityLogicalName) &&
            aliased.AttributeLogicalName == attributeName);


        /// I believe there is a bug in CRM 2011 when dealing with aggregate values of a linked entity in FetchXML.
        /// Even though it is marked with an alias, the AliasedValue in the Attribute collection will use the 
        /// actual CRM name, rather than the aliased one, even though the AttributeCollection's key will correctly
        /// use the aliased name.  So if the aliased Attribute Logical Name doesn't match the assumed attribute name
        /// value, check to see if the entity contains an AliasedValue with that key whose attribute logical name 
        /// doesn't match the key (the assumed bug), and mark it as being the aliased attribute
        if (!value && aliased != null && entity.Contains(attributeName))
        {
            var aliasedByKey = entity[attributeName] as AliasedValue;
            if (aliasedByKey != null && aliasedByKey.AttributeLogicalName != attributeName && 
                Object.ReferenceEquals(aliased, aliasedByKey))
            {
                value = true;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the Aliased Value for a column specified in a Linked entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the aliased attribute form the linked entity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <param name="attributeName">The aliased attribute from the linked entity.  Can be preappeneded with the
    /// linked entities logical name and a period. ie "Contact.LastName"</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool HasAliasedAttribute(this Entity entity, string attributeName)
    {
        string aliasedEntityName = SplitAliasedAttributeEntityName(ref attributeName);
        return entity.Attributes.Values.Any(a =>
            entity.IsAttributeAliasedValue(attributeName, aliasedEntityName, a as AliasedValue));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles spliting the attributeName if it is formated as "EntityAliasedName.AttributeName",
    /// updating the attribute name and returning the aliased EntityName
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attributeName"></param>
    /// <param name="aliasedEntityName"></param>
    private static string SplitAliasedAttributeEntityName(ref string attributeName)
    {
        string aliasedEntityName = null;
        if (attributeName.Contains('.'))
        {
            var split = attributeName.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (split.Length != 2)
            {
                throw new Exception("Attribute Name was specified for an Alaised Value with " + split.Length +
                " split parts, and two were expected.  Attribute Name = " + attributeName);
            }
            aliasedEntityName = split[0];
            attributeName = split[1];
        }

        return aliasedEntityName;
    }
```

Comment: "you can't retrieve child entities for an entity with a single query", this isnt strictly true, there are a couple of methods that would support this behaviour. For example RetrieveRequest and FetchXml. Also "You can, on the other hand, include values from child entities by added columns to the column collection of the linked entity." I would say that is querying the child entities as well, technically you are making a join to another table.